# Byte compile emacs lisp file: Error: Cannot open load file

Tags: emacs, elisp, dired

I am using Gnu Emacs 24.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.
I downloaded `dired+.el` from here: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el . I then tried to byte-compile this file in Emacs. I made a file `bytecomp.el` :

```
(byte-compile-file "dired+.el")
```

and run the following command:

```
bash$ emacs -batch -l bytecomp.el -kill
```

and got the following error message:

```
In toplevel form:
dired+.el:1114:1:Error: Cannot open load file: dired+
```

### Update

Changing the file `bytecomp.el` to:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs/test/bytecompile")
(byte-compile-file "dired+.el")
```

and running `emacs -batch -l bytecomp.el -kill` from the same directory ( `~/emacs/test/bytecompile` ) gives another error message:

```
Recursive load: "/home/fcihh/emacs/test/bytecompile/bytecomp.el", "/home/fcihh/emacs/test/bytecompile/bytecomp.el", "/home/fcihh/emacs/test/bytecompile/bytecomp.el", "/home/fcihh/emacs/test/bytecompile/bytecomp.el", "/home/fcihh/emacs/test/bytecompile/bytecomp.el"
```

Comment: Is `dired+.el` in directory `~/emacs/test/bytecompile`?  If not, is its directory in your `load-path`?

Comment: @Drew Yes it is in the same directory..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `dired+.el` in your `load-path`.

`dired+.el` explicitly does this:

```
(provide 'dired+)
(require 'dired+) ; Ensure loaded before compile this.
```

This is an Emacs-Lisp idiom that ensures that the library is loaded before compiling it.  For Dired+ this is appropriate.

So do this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/your/path/to/dired+/")
```

The relevant doc for the idiom used here is (elisp) `Named Features`.  Here is a bit of it:

```
Although top-level calls to `require' are evaluated during byte
compilation, `provide' calls are not.  Therefore, you can ensure that a
file of definitions is loaded before it is byte-compiled by including a
`provide' followed by a `require' for the same feature, as in the
following example.

  (provide 'my-feature)  ; Ignored by byte compiler,
                         ;   evaluated by `load'.
  (require 'my-feature)  ; Evaluated by byte compiler.

The compiler ignores the `provide', then processes the `require' by
loading the file in question.  Loading the file does execute the
`provide' call, so the subsequent `require' call does nothing when the
file is loaded.
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it.. but now I get another error about "Recursive load" on the file `bytecomp.el`..

Comment: Dunno why you are making something complicated out of this, but try adding `-l dired+.el` before `-l bytecomp.el`.  (Or just open Emacs, load `dired+.el`, then `M-x byte-compile-file dired+.el`.  Or use `L` and then `B` in Dired, on `dired+.el`.)  The point is that `dired+.el` needs to be loaded before you compile it.

Comment: I would like to automate the byte compilation from a `bash` script. That is why I do it complicated :)

Comment: Rename your file from `bytecomp.el`. There is already a standard Emacs library with that name.  This might be confusing things a bit.

Comment: What happens if you do only `emacs -batch -l dired+.el --eval (byte-compile-file "/your/path/to/dired+.el")`?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a file to compile `dired+.el`.  Just invoke the byte compiler directly from the command line:

```
$ emacs -Q --batch -L . -f batch-byte-compile dired+.el
```

Before invoking this command, **remove your `bytecomp.el` file**, or at least rename it to something else, e.g. `my-byte-compilation.el`.

Your `bytecomp.el` file shadows the built-in Emacs library `bytecomp.el`, which defines `byte-compile-file` and a couple of other byte compilation functions, including the above `batch-byte-compile`.

When calling `byte-compile-file`, Emacs tries to load the implementing library `bytecomp.el` to have the function definition available.  However, since you named your file `bytecomp.el`, and placed the containing directory in front of `load-path`, Emacs actually tries to load *your* file again.

This in turn leads to another call to `byte-compile-file`, which again triggers a load of `bytecomp.el`.  Hence the recursive load error, you saw.